# Putting sampled values into a matrix- simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I put values into a matrix in simulink? For example, if I sampled a sine wave every 0.5s, and put that value into a fixed size matrix of size N. After the matrix is full, it would overwrite the oldest values.

Comment: Have you looked at the assignment block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about using the matrix as if it's a buffer, then if you have the DSP Blockset you can use the Buffer block.  Otherwise this is pretty straight forward to do using a MATLAB function block (see code below).  If the matrix is constructed by another part of your model, then that can be passed as a second input to the MATLAB Function block and the (new element) insertion code modified appropriately.

```
function y = custom_buffer(u)
%#codegen

persistent buffer next_index

buf_size = 1000;

% Define initial values
if isempty(buffer)
    buffer = zeros(buf_size,1);
    next_index = 1;
end

% Populate the buffer
buffer(next_index) = u;

% Increment the location to write to at the next time
if next_index < buf_size
    next_index = next_index + 1;
else
    next_index = 1;
end

% Populate the output
y = buffer;
```